# Send data to next view controller after QR Code read

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, qr-code

I'm hoping i'm missing something pretty simple here, but I can't seem to get my head around it!

I am reading a QR code and pushing to my next view controller once the QR code has been read:

```
if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            let qrData = metadataObj.stringValue

            let segueViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("confirmScan") as? ScanConfirm
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(segueViewController!, animated: true)
            captureSession?.stopRunning() }
```

I would then like to pass the data found in the QR code and show it in my next view's label. I have tried using prepareForSegue but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let NextViewController : ScanConfirm = segue.destinationViewController as! ScanConfirm
    NextViewController.newLabel.text = qrData
}
```

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: after you get the qrData, you can simply call performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: Take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29846611/765298

Comment: I guess `newLabel` is just not created until you move to your `NextViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create a property in **ScanConform** class

```
class ScanConform: UIViewController {
var scanData:String?
```

> you can place below code viewdidload or viewwillapper

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
guard let displayData = scanData else { return }
newLabel.text = displayData
     }
}
```

> While Setting Data Do Like this

```
if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
        let qrData = metadataObj.stringValue

        let segueViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("confirmScan") as? ScanConfirm
segueViewController.scanData = grData    
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(segueViewController!, animated: true)
        captureSession?.stopRunning()
 }
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked perfectly. Thank you all very much for your 'swift' responses!